# Angularjs 2 ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat in angularjs 2 with custom template but it's not working

**`html`**

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in itemList">
    <td>{{data.test}}</td>
</tr>
```

**`.ts`**

```
import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'app/hello.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

    public itemList = [
      {name:"Apple", test:"1"},
      {name:"Orange", test:"2"},
      {name:"Grapes", test:"3"},
   ];


}
```

I don't know what is the problem. It's working in Angularjs 1 but Angularjs 2 not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)** instead of ng-repeat. There is no ng-repeat with angular2.

Change it as,

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of itemList">
    <td>{{data.test}}</td>
</tr>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/XYmvRfVkrMtKC6RQY2GH?p=preview)**

Comment: can you please give me full syntax

Comment: @Dev the above is the full syntax

Comment: EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property ("
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let data of itemList">
    <td>{{data.test}}</td>
</tr>

Comment: What is the version you are using? check the demo

Comment: @Dev check the demo attached

Comment: it shows error Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known native property

Comment: @Dev did you check the demo

Comment: Ya Same Procedure only i followd

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is full syntax of code.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `

  <p>List:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of itemList">
      {{ item.name }} {{item.test}}
    </li>
  </ul>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public carsList: Array<string>;
  public itemList = [
    { name: "Apple", test: "1" },
    { name: "Orange", test: "2" },
    { name: "Grapes", test: "3" },
  ];
}
```